# spring webflux all api's giving UnsupportedMediaTypeException

Tags: java, spring, gson, spring-webflux

I have a `@SpringBootApplication` using Gson instead of jackson with the following converter:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public GsonBuilder gsonBuilder(){
        final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        // I registerTypeAdapter 's here
        return gson;
    }
}
```

I now have my controller (this fails on all of them not just this but they are the same syntax)

```
@RestController("/1/api/release/")
@Log
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReleaseController {

   @PostMapping("blocked")
public Mono<ServerResponse> issueIsBlocked() {
    return Mono.just("test")
            .flatMap(s -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(s))
            .onErrorResume(Throwable.class, e -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).bodyValue(e.getMessage()));
}
}
```

And application.properties contains

```
spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
spring.codec.max-in-memory-size=10MB
```

I however get this error

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType=java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.unsupportedError(BodyInserters.java:391)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$writeWithMessageWriters$11(BodyInserters.java:381)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.writeWithMessageWriters(BodyInserters.java:381)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$fromValue$1(BodyInserters.java:98)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$BodyInserterResponse.writeToInternal(DefaultServerResponseBuilder.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$AbstractServerResponse.writeTo(DefaultServerResponseBuilder.java:351)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.write(AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.java:311)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.lambda$handle$2(AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.java:264)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1705)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2267)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2075)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1949)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:135)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:45)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:97)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:100)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:390)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:185)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:97)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:185)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:251)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1752)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreInner.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:235)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1944)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:185)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:174)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:359)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2267)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2075)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1949)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:64)
at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:228)
at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:465)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:90)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:170)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <!-- Exclude the default Jackson dependency -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

things i have noticed:

- the error appears before my method is even entered, so it shouldn't really have anything to do with error handling specified there.
- I tried adding type adapters for LinkedHashMap however they were still not caught. However if this is what is needed, I am currently only adding them for the WebClient not however spring is handling conversion. I am simply guessing here however I would assume it took the GSON bean i specified in my configuration, in which case it would be there.

  - If i look at BodyInserters:376 context.messageWriters() I see nothing familiar to stuff I added explicitly.

How can I get my api's to work?

Comment: Can you provide an MRE as I am unable to reproduce this.

Comment: I updated the question. I have created a test project and included only the files that are currently pasted in the question and am able to trigger it with just those. For clarification this happens in the logs when I trigger the rest api on the app launched through intellij.

Comment: You are using services that aren't defined anywhere, and you return gson without building it. Obviously you have those in your own code, but could you provide a working minimal example of the issue

Comment: fixed again sorry forgot to remove some small things.  From my further research it seems like spring webflux doesn't support gson that well, and i have ended up reverting to jackson as this has already taken up several days and i can't prorgess without it.

Comment: why the `flatMap`

Comment: @shahaf flatmap allows you to return a mono. Map is synchronous

Comment: @123, is there any value for it compared to `map` on non IO blocking operation (cpu intensive) like `ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(s)` (assuming it's non IO blocking)?

Comment: @mangusbrother After looking at the docs, I doubt this would work with either Jackson,GSON or any serializer. `Mono<ServerResponse>` isn't supposed to be returned from controllers, you're supposed to use it if you are using `RouterFunction`

Comment: @shahaf I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to use `Mono<ServerReponse>` in controllers, as such it doesn't appear to be mapped correctly by any serializer.

There are two alternatives

1. Use response entity

   ```
   @PostMapping("blocked")
   public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> issueIsBlocked() {
       return Mono.just("test")
           .map(s -> new ResponseEntity<>(s, HttpStatus.OK))
           .onErrorResume(Throwable.class, 
               e -> Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR))
            );
   }
   ```

2.Use the RouterFunction provided by webflux

```
@Configuration
public class RouterConfig {

    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> home() {
    return route(POST("/blocked"),
            request -> Mono.just("test")
                    .flatMap(s -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(s))
                    .onErrorResume(Throwable.class, e ->
                            ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).bodyValue(e.getMessage())
                    ));
    }
```

Comment: Hi...i don t know why your solution does not worked for me...i m using the RouterFunction i tried to return a file  as an InputStream and as ResourceRegion but i always get UnsupportedMediaTypeException regardless the extension of the file....pls help :(

Comment: @Daveus post a question with your code and I'll have a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630463/unsupportedmediatypeexception-with-spring-and-reactor
Here you are...

Comment: sorry forgot to tag u ahahah!